# WPF:Enclose controls within a child window chrome which has a close button

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

I'm a C++ programmer and I've started a side project to teach me some WPF. I've started making a desktop app to browse images and probably retouch them, something like paint.net.

I want to enclose controls(e.g. see image below) within a child window chrome which has a close button. Something like MDI, but not quite.
[image]

The simplest way for now, I thought, was to enclose it within another `<window></window>`, but it seems WPF doesn't like this. It gives a runtime exception.

Is there a simpler way of doing it. I couldn't find any links that explained anything similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Window you need to create a new Window class in a separate file which you can then instantiate and show from your main Window's code.

```
var childWindow = new MyChildWindow();
childWindow.Show();
```

To get the simplified window chrome set WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow in MyChildWindow.

If you're trying to create a contained simulated window inside your main window that needs to use a normal non-Window control. Silverlight includes a ChildWindow class but it's not built into WPF. To create something similar you can use a HeaderedContentControl which you'll have to style to look like a tool window by modifying the ControlTemplate. You'll also need to create behaviors like drag, resize and close on the control which is usually best handled by making it a custom control.

Comment: Thanks a ton John. This sounds promising. Will try it out tomorrow.

Comment: This works, but if I try to write a XAML equivalent it doesn't.

Comment: There isn't a direct way to declare a Window instance in XAML because a Window can only be a root element, not a child of another WPF type (it's controlled by the OS as an HWND rather than the WPF layout system as a FrameworkElement). Calling methods on elements also doesn't work in XAML.